# Prove that these determinants are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Without calculating the determinant, prove:

$
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & x & y & z \\
x & 0 & z & y \\
y & z & 0 & x \\
z & y & x & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & z^2 & y^2 \\
1 & z^2 & 0 & x^2 \\
1 & y^2 & x^2 & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please consider updating your question with some information about what you have tried or where you are getting stuck. You will find people are much more willing to help if you do!

Comment: What a lovely welcome :D Um..I'm new in the field of linear algebra so I don't actually have any idea how to solve this. Maybe I need to add the first row to the other ones. Would that be helpful at all?

Comment: Please specify what kind of calculations **are** allowed to solve this question

Comment: Adding rows and columns, using linear combinations, multiplying rows and columns by a scalar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll do the proof in the case $x,y,z \neq 0$. Start with the right-hand matrix, and multiply the second, third and fourth rows by $x,y,z$ respectively, and do the same with the columns. You will get

$$ \begin{vmatrix}
0 & x & y & z \\
x & 0 & z^2 xy & y^2 xz \\
y & z^2 xy & 0 & x^2 yz\\
z & y^2 xz & x^2 yz & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

Moreover, this process multiplies the determinant by $x^2 y^2 z^2$. To counteract this, let's divide the second, third, and fourth columns by $xyz$. Then we get

$$ \begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1/yz & 1/xz & 1/xy \\
x & 0 & z & y \\
y & z & 0 & x\\
z & y & x & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

Now we are off by a factor of $(xyz)^2/(xyz)^3 = 1/(xyz)$. But we can return to our original determinant by multiplying the top row by $xyz$, to get

$$ \begin{vmatrix}
0 & x & y & z \\
x & 0 & z & y \\
y & z & 0 & x\\
z & y & x & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}$$